# I have this issue when trying to read my data which is json encoded from the php page to the swift page

Tags: php, json, swift, xcode

I have this issue when trying to read my data which is json encoded from the php page to the swift page.

this is the code I am using

```
import Foundation

protocol HomeModelProtocol: class {
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}


class HomeModel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {

    //properties

    weak var delegate: HomeModelProtocol!

    var data = Data()

    let urlPath: String = "http://localhost/service.php" //this will be changed to the path where service.php lives
func downloadItems() {

        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to download data")
            }else {
                print("Data downloaded") // this work fine

                self.parseJSON(data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }

func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {

    var jsonResult = NSArray()
    print(jsonResult) // this print empty parentheses


    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)) // this prints out the array

    //the code below throughs an arror
   do{
    jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [NSArray] as NSArray
        print(jsonResult)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)

    }



    var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
    let locations = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
    {

        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

        let location = LocationModel()

        //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
        if let name = jsonElement["Name"] as? String,
            let address = jsonElement["Address"] as? String,
            let latitude = jsonElement["Latitude"] as? String,
            let longitude = jsonElement["Longitude"] as? String
        {

            location.name = name
            location.address = address
            location.latitude = latitude
            location.longitude = longitude

        }

        locations.add(location)

    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

        self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: locations)

    })
}
}
```

this is the output which I am receiving:

```
Data downloaded

(
)

Optional(" \nconnectedinside[{\"name\":\"One\",\"add\":\"One\",\"lat\":\"1\",\"long\":\"1\"},{\"name\":\"Two\",\"add\":\"Two\",\"lat\":\"2\",\"long\":\"2\"},{\"name\":\"One\",\"add\":\"One\",\"lat\":\"1\",\"long\":\"1\"},{\"name\":\"Two\",\"add\":\"Two\",\"lat\":\"2\",\"long\":\"2\"}]")
```

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around
>   character 2." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around
>   character 2.}

Comment: Are you getting all that output, including `Data downloaded () ...`?

Comment: and you should use Codable instead.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson -->  print("Data downloaded") shows output yes and this line displays the array content: print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)) // this prints out the array

Comment: Your downloaded data isn’t correct json, you should fix it on the php side if possible

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you, you are right I fixed the php page and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error, because the json response you receive is not an array but a dictionary.
EDIT: as pointed out in a comment, you first need to fix your json response in your php code. There is ":" missing after "connectedinside".
It should look like this:
`{\"connectedinside\":[{\"name\":\"One\",\"add\":"One",...},...]}`

My suggestion to fix this:

You should have two models:

```
struct HomeModelResponse: Codable {
   let connectedinside: [LocationModel]
}

// your LocationModel should look like this:
struct LocationModel: Codable {
   let name: String
   let add: String
   let lat: String
   let long: String
}
```

And change your JSONDecoding code to:

```
do {
   jsonResult = try? JSONDecoder().decode(HomeModelResponse.self, from: data)
   print()
} catch let exception {
   print("received exception while decoding: \(exception)"
}
```

Then you can access your LocationModels by jsonResult.connectedinside

Comment: Why are you decoding with JSONSerialization when your structs support Codable?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on my php side and I fixed it.it is working now.